# How do I avoid memory leak when closing a QWebView?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qt5, qwebview

I do call close() on my main window's exit event but I can see on console memory leaks; such as:

```
LEAK: 3 XMLHttpRequest
LEAK: 26 CachedResource
LEAK: 293 WebCoreNode
```

I do close the browser like this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);
    webControl.close();
}
```

`webControl`is of [`QWebPage`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html) type and MainWindow is [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html).

What's the proper way to way to close the web browser control soon as close the main window is requested so that I can avoid such memory leaks?

Comment: make sure that all the allocated memory is free,

Comment: Is this a WebKit `QWebView`?

Comment: Can you give us more informations about what allocate in that class? Maybe the code in a gist or something?

Comment: I vaguely remember having similar output on an old project. I never investigated it (din't write it), but i would consider the possibility that it is just QWebViews fault. It's not even maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having answered it before, there it is: [Memory leak in QWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525400/memory-leak-in-qwebview).

This answer was for a previous version of Qt (5.4.2), but I found out that it still affects the recent versions: see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57272) and [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56774).

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about it, as all these reported bugs were not solved yet in the latest version (Qt5.9.2).